# Harware-accelerated image (png or jpg) decoding in Android?

Tags: android, gpu, png, jpeg, decoding

I'm working on batch processing photos in Android mobile device.

I've tried multiple standard & third-party libraries and found that they uses `libjpeg-turbo` and `libpng` internally via SKIA library and they are CPU-based.

I don't render much objects when processing, so it would be great if I can exploit GPUs. Is there any recommendations or reading materials? Thanks!

For standard libraries, I've tried [ImageDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder) and [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory) to load/subsample/decode thousands of photos.

For third-party libraries, I've tried [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/) and [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/), `glide` was not as fast as `ImageDecoder` and `coil` was not working... IDK